# Want to increase my utorrent android speed

Tags: wi-fi

I am using Galaxy A7 . My downloading speed is very worse 2kbbs it takes several weeks for a movie download.I am fed up really. Now a movie with 0/101 peers and seed 5/8 is downloading in 2 kbbs with my wify which has the capacity of max 60kbbs around. Please  I need a solution for this ..

Comment: Wifi devices usually have capacity in MBps. What kind of wifi device do you have? Did you mean your connection speed is 60kbps max? Try a torrent like [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent) and tell us the maximum speed you're able to reach.

Comment: if you really sure the blame is on the wi-fi speed, you can actually download with your PC and transfer to your device by cable

Answer (score 1):

Your download speed is quite slow and the number of seeders are few.This is the main reason that it takes lot of time for you to download. Check the ratio, seeder should seed until at least 1.000 Ratio.

Along with those see whether this can help. Go to
Preferences --> Bandwidth --> "Disable the "Apply rate limit to uTP connections" option.

Answer (score 0):

The torrent lacks peers (and even seeds are too low). Find yourself another alternative torrent.

On side note, you can try some other torrent application, since sometimes that has greatly worked for me. For example, using [aTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilityflow.torrent) I was able to download a movie trailer with just 2 seeds with significant speeds.